# How to make 2d List and how to use it

Tags: java, list

So I am making a student grades calculator and I want to use the List<> but I don't want to use it the normal way where it will contain stuff in the normal order : [x,y,1,3]

I want to make it so that I have the List and inside that I will have many small lists that will contain the name of the student and after that all the grades that student has.

How can I make such a list and then access it?

Comment: Just make a `Student` object to contain all that information. `Student(String name, int[] grades)` for example. Then you can just say: `Student[] students = ...;`. Java is an OOP language, you should use it as one :)

Comment: I really mean to be helpful when I say this: You should buy a book on any programming language and read it. All you need to do, as Obicere has said, is put your objects in it. But I think you would really benefit from just reading any programming book and coming up with this on your own. Since this is a really fundamental question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend holding `Student` grades inside of your `Student` object

```
public class Student {
  private String name;
  private int[] grades;

  public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grades = new int[10];
  }

  public void setGrade(int assignmentNumber, int grade) {
    grades[assignmentNumber] = grade;
  }

  public int[] getGrades() {
    return grades;
  }
}
```

Then create an `ArrayList` of type `Student` and use the getter to get that student's grades

```
List<Student> roster = new ArrayList<Student>();
Student stu = new Student("Bob");
stu.setGrade(0, 100);
roster.add(stu);
```

You can now call the getter to get the array of grades

```
roster.get(0).getGrades();
```